# Instantiating custom PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer from spring context

Tags: java, spring

I want to define a custom PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer in spring context xml. I want to use there multiple PropertySources, so that I can load part of the configuration from several property files and provide other part dynamically by my custom PropertySource implementation. The advantage is that it should be then easy to adjust the order of loading these property sources just by making modifications to the xml spring configuration.

And here I run into a problem: how to define an arbitrary list of PropertySources and inject it into PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer, so that it uses the sources defined by me?

Seems to be a basic thing that should be provided by spring, but since yesterday I cannot find a way to do it. Using  namespace would enable me to load several property files, but I also need to define the id of the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer (as other projects refer to it), and also I want to use my custom implementation. That is why I am defining the bean explicitly and not using the namespace.

The most intuitive way would be to inject a list of PropertySources into PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer like this:

```
<bean id="applicationPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />     
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
    <property name="propertySources">
        <list>
             <!-- my PropertySource objects -->
        </list>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

but unfortunately propertySources is of type PropertySources and does not accept a list. The PropertySources interface has one and only implementor which is MutablePropertySources, which indeed stores list of PropertySource objects, but has no constructor nor setter through which I can inject this list. It only has add*(PropertySource) methods.

The only workaround I see now is to implement my own PropertySources class, extending MutablePropertySources, which would accept list of PropertySource objects on creation and manually add it via using add*(PropertySource) method. But why so much workaround would be needed to provide something that I thought was supposed to be the main reason of introducing the PropertySources (having flexible configuration manageable from spring configuration level).

Please clarify what am I getting wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

I use java config for that, dont know if any fields changed between spring version, but maybe it will help you:

```
 public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        properties.setLocations(new ClassPathResource[]{
                new ClassPathResource("config/file1.properties"),
                new ClassPathResource("config/file2.properties")
        });
        properties.setLocalOverride(true);
        properties.setBeanName("beanName");
        properties.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
        return properties;
    }
```

Comment: not really as what i need is PropertySources coming from several  different places, not only from property files, and locations are only for class path resources.. i think this is what was already there before introducing PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer in Spring 3.1 .. i wanted to utilize this new class in some clever way now..

Comment: it accepts implementations of org.springframework.core.io.Resource so ClassPathResource is not the only option : ) what exactly do you want to set as property in this case?

Comment: I want to set my custom implementation of PropertySource (my own class that implements PropertySource) which will internally call another service to fetch the properties on runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
<property name="propertySources">
        <list>
             <!-- my PropertySource objects -->
        </list>
</property>
```

Use something like :

```
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/my.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:my.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```